# python - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, file-handling

```
file = open('file.txt' , 'wb')

text_in_bytes_format = '''\O£”Ã Ø<RVrF>ýt­Lš:]:B÷(2öÞ{åÐ5"-V¥D1¦òÒm° –^yêŒ·çNxrÌoTÑ³np$h/ñLˆ>U×bSƒƒxd‚`óJà(æçÛ‰#dõ'ŸÊ¤ÇŸVá0Üsß=r÷=÷ê:W«“ÇNÈ²UëeÆŒ™ê—éÀ§.Jÿ†šœýz«~êü;J×Oà©î•£’áæLªîq¨?{’ZæúëŸ_‰³Á¯­ùóHzNyéëß”,v8oÚ²0TCðÎ9èV0‡\ò¼qmÆç—ßPø
ýŒ%Ta*çý¾Þ`3€r )Ü“êqcL›k4
Õ¾Ä!áß>2‚ë/¹lªz=ùëïg>lÌ9zL–c=á¦Hé13ö~]ü.¤“‡`SÄj<Wž–¬¬ˆD4'''

file.write(text_in_bytes_format)
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

There are a couple of solutions to this problem on the internet, but my problem is slightly different because the text I am trying to write is in bytes format.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Try `text_in_bytes_format = b'''\O£”Ã Ø<RVrF....'''`.

Comment: What is that string of characters supposed to represent? Where did you get it from? Is it supposed to be encoded in some way?

Comment: @ekhumoro, I just selected some text in a random png file and put it into this program.

Comment: @Lenovo360 What are you actually trying to achieve by doing that? At the moment, your question doesn't make much sense. That string clearly cannot possibly be bytes, because it contains non-ascii characters.

Comment: @CoolCloud: If I use the `b''` string, I get an error: `SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.`

Comment: @Lenovo360 Sorry, but you're now making even less sense. Text does not have a "character set" and it cannot be "in bytes format". Text is unicode. To convert it to bytes, you must choose an encoding. The string in your question is just a sequence of *unicode text characters*. It is niot formatted in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @Lenovo360 You still haven't explained what is meant by "selected some text in a random png file and put it into this program". Image files contain *binary data*, not text. What program did you use to open the file? If you want to copy binary data into a python string literal, you must firstly convert it into a representation that python understands. You can't just copy and paste random data from one program to another - you'll just end up with garbage (like the string shown in your question).

Comment: @ekhumoro: So I opened a PNG file with a text editor (The default windows notepad). It contained some data, so I just copied a part of it and pasted it into my program.

Comment: One of your comments says: `I already asked the OP to explain what they're trying to do. `. Here's what I am actually trying to achieve. So assume I have a string which is `'O£”Ã Ø<'`. Now when I encode that string to some other encoding (eg - UTF-8), assume I will get an output like `'{åÐ5"-V'`. As you can see here, the normal string and the encoded string have different characters. I don't want that, because specific applications can only read specific characters. For example, if I am writing to a `word` file, `word` won't be able to read that file if I am encoding it differently.

Comment: @Lenovo360 To repeat: *text does not have an encoding*. So to write it to a file *you must choose an encoding yourself* when converting it to bytes. This cannot be avoided. If a program is umable to determine the right encoding itself, you will have to explicitly tell it what the correct encoding is.

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit confused -- at least regarding terminology if not more
fundamental issues. String literals in Python 3 are Unicode text by default
(type of `str` not `bytes`).

```
text = 'foo'        # A string literal.
print(type(text))   # <class 'str'>
```

Python does support literal byte strings too:

```
some_bytes = b'foo'
print(type(some_bytes))   # <class 'bytes'>
```

But your text is not currently a literal byte string. For example, using
a small snippet of your text, we can attempt to create a literal byte string:

```
 text = b'B÷(2öÞ'   # SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.
```

Here's what that snippet would look like as a byte literal (i.e, after
running it through `text.encode('utf-8')`):

```
some_bytes = b'B\xc3\xb7(2\xc3\xb6\xc3\x9e'
```

Back to your code:

```
# You have some literal text, so don't give it
# a variable name implying that it is bytes.
text = 'B÷(2öÞ'

# Convert to bytes.
bs = text.encode('utf-8')

# Open a file for writing bytes directly.
# BTW, it's also a good idea to open/close files using `with` context manager.
with open('file.txt' , 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(bs)
```

Some of your comments indicate that the text is not Unicode text or has some
unknown encoding. If so, you have a bigger problem and/or cannot use it
directly as a **string literal** in a Python program (you might need to read
the data in from a file, for example, and tell Python the file encoding
before reading in the data).

If you haven't read it already, Ned Batchelder's presentation on [Unicode
and Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#1) can clarify these issues and get you pointed in the right
direction regarding terminology and naming.

Comment: The OP says they "just selected some text in a random png file". So it sounds like they opened it in a text editor in order to copy part of it. The question is: what encoding did the text editor guess when it decoded the bytes? If it didn't guess utf-8, your current solution will produce a junk file.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, as implied by "if so, you have a bigger problem".

Comment: It's only a problem because they opened a non-text file *as text*. The encoding is a total red herring, so it doesn't make much sense to talk about unicode at all. Judging from the OPs comment on another answer, they sort of seem aware of that. What they really need to do is open the file in non-text/binary mode and copy the contents *as bytes*.

Comment: I already asked the OP to explain what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert it to bytes first. You can do this by using `bytes()`

```py
file = open('file.txt' , 'wb')

text_in_bytes_format = '''\O£”Ã Ø<RVrF>ýt­Lš:]:B÷(2öÞ{åÐ5"-V¥D1¦òÒm° –^yêŒ·çNxrÌoTÑ³np$h/ñLˆ>U×bSƒƒxd‚`óJà(æçÛ‰#dõ'ŸÊ¤ÇŸVá0Üsß=r÷=÷ê:W«“ÇNÈ²UëeÆŒ™ê—éÀ§.Jÿ†šœýz«~êü;J×Oà©î•£’áæLªîq¨?{’ZæúëŸ_‰³Á¯­ùóHzNyéëß”,v8oÚ²0TCðÎ9èV0‡\ò¼qmÆç—ßPø
ýŒ%Ta*çý¾Þ`3€r )Ü“êqcL›k4
Õ¾Ä!áß>2‚ë/¹lªz=ùëïg>lÌ9zL–c=á¦Hé13ö~]ü.¤“‡`SÄj<Wž–¬¬ˆD4'''
b = bytes(text_in_bytes_format, 'utf-8')
file.write(b)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I have the string encoded in some other character set other than utf-8, how can I write the file with that same encoding?

Comment: You could pass in the encoding as a separate variable

Answer (score 0):

```
file.write(text_in_bytes_format.encode())
```

Comment: This uses UTF-8 encoding just like my answer.